# Equation $\frac{1}{a_1}+\ldots +\frac{1}{a_{2018}} = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, diophantine-equations, parity

Let $A_{n}=\{(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n}): a_i\in\mathbb{Z_{>0}}|\ \ \frac{1}{a_1}+\ldots \frac{1}{a_{n}} = 1\}$.

> My question. What is $|A_n|\operatorname{mod}2$, for $n=2018$? That is
>   what is the parity of cardinality of $A_n$, for $n=2018$.

I can solve this problem for numbers of the type $n=2^i+2^k$. But in the case $n=2018$ 
I find it more interesting.

Also I'm interesting where such equations can arise.

Comment: Well, such equations often arise at MSE :D

Comment: @Ennar, that's  already really nice)

Comment: We have a pretty strict policy for ongoing competitions, and your problem has a seemingly arbitrary 2018 in it, which is quite common for competitions this year. Just to be on the safe side: where is this problem from?

Comment: For n=10 this problem was proposed on Putnam. For n=2018  I want to solve it, because it is more difficult and interesting